# Require java 11 Dockerfile based on alpine or equivalent size image for Arm32 platform

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

Using **docker** and the alpine base I used to build a Java 8 application, I had one Dockerfile image for Intel based linux, and another for arm 32bit linux. Then for Intel I moved to Java 11 and created a new Dockerfile that continues to use alpine but now first of all builds a cutdown Java runtime (using jlink) and then bundles this with my appliccation this is working fine - https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/songkongdocker/src/187401c6f53618103a20707fab06257ce1953500/Dockerfile

(note the complicated 2nd apk line is just copied from the openjdk Dockerfile, seems neccessary to run Java on Alpine)

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine AS build

RUN /opt/java/openjdk/bin/jlink --module-path=/opt/java/openjdk/jmods \
--add-modules java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.net.http,java.prefs,java.scripting,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.scripting.nashorn,jdk.jcmd,jdk.crypto.ec \
--output /opt/songkong/jre

RUN apk --no-cache add \
      curl \
      tini
 
RUN mkdir -p /opt \
 && curl http://www.jthink.net/songkong/downloads/current/songkong-linux-docker.tgz?val=1120| tar -C /opt -xzf - \
&& find /opt/songkong -perm /u+x -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a+x

RUN rm -fr /opt/java

FROM alpine:3.11

ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps curl binutils \
    && GLIBC_VER="2.31-r0" \
    && ALPINE_GLIBC_REPO="https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download" \
    && GCC_LIBS_URL="https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/g/gcc-libs/gcc-libs-9.1.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz" \
    && GCC_LIBS_SHA256="91dba90f3c20d32fcf7f1dbe91523653018aa0b8d2230b00f822f6722804cf08" \
    && ZLIB_URL="https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/z/zlib/zlib-1%3A1.2.11-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz" \
    && ZLIB_SHA256=17aede0b9f8baa789c5aa3f358fbf8c68a5f1228c5e6cba1a5dd34102ef4d4e5 \
    && curl -LfsS https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
    && SGERRAND_RSA_SHA256="823b54589c93b02497f1ba4dc622eaef9c813e6b0f0ebbb2f771e32adf9f4ef2" \
    && echo "${SGERRAND_RSA_SHA256} */etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub" | sha256sum -c - \
    && curl -LfsS ${ALPINE_GLIBC_REPO}/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk > /tmp/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && apk add --no-cache /tmp/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && curl -LfsS ${ALPINE_GLIBC_REPO}/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk > /tmp/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && apk add --no-cache /tmp/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && curl -Ls ${ALPINE_GLIBC_REPO}/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk > /tmp/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && apk add --no-cache /tmp/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef --force --inputfile POSIX --charmap UTF-8 "$LANG" || true \
    && echo "export LANG=$LANG" > /etc/profile.d/locale.sh \
    && curl -LfsS ${GCC_LIBS_URL} -o /tmp/gcc-libs.tar.xz \
    && echo "${GCC_LIBS_SHA256} */tmp/gcc-libs.tar.xz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && mkdir /tmp/gcc \
    && tar -xf /tmp/gcc-libs.tar.xz -C /tmp/gcc \
    && mv /tmp/gcc/usr/lib/libgcc* /tmp/gcc/usr/lib/libstdc++* /usr/glibc-compat/lib \
    && strip /usr/glibc-compat/lib/libgcc_s.so.* /usr/glibc-compat/lib/libstdc++.so* \
    && curl -LfsS ${ZLIB_URL} -o /tmp/libz.tar.xz \
    && echo "${ZLIB_SHA256} */tmp/libz.tar.xz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && mkdir /tmp/libz \
    && tar -xf /tmp/libz.tar.xz -C /tmp/libz \
    && mv /tmp/libz/usr/lib/libz.so* /usr/glibc-compat/lib \
    && apk del --purge .build-deps glibc-i18n \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*.apk /tmp/gcc /tmp/gcc-libs.tar.xz /tmp/libz /tmp/libz.tar.xz /var/cache/apk/*
    
RUN mkdir -p /opt

COPY --from=build /opt/songkong /opt/songkong

RUN apk --no-cache add \
      ca-certificates \
      curl \
      fontconfig \
      msttcorefonts-installer \
      tini \
 && update-ms-fonts \
 && fc-cache -f
    
EXPOSE 4567

# Config, License, Logs, Reports and Internal Database
VOLUME /songkong

# Music folder should be mounted here
VOLUME /music

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/songkong/songkong.sh"]
CMD ["-r"]
```

But now I am trying to update my arm32 dockerfile, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an alpine based openjdk11 docker file for arm32. In fact Java 11 not officially supported for 32bit, however there does seem to be a version based on **Centos** instead. So I have created a new Dockerfile based on Centos but the image created is **over twice as large** as the alpine one

https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/songkongdockerarm32/src/7a37e6d88f705d6f54301de4b6fa7090ffedbcc8/Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:armv7l-centos-jdk-11.0.11_9 AS build

RUN /opt/java/openjdk/bin/jlink --module-path=/opt/java/openjdk/jmods \
--add-modules java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.net.http,java.prefs,java.scripting,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.scripting.nashorn,jdk.jcmd,jdk.crypto.ec \
--output /opt/songkong/jre
 
RUN mkdir -p /opt \
 && curl http://www.jthink.net/songkong/downloads/current/songkong-linux-docker.tgz?val=11311| tar -C /opt -xzf - \
&& find /opt/songkong -perm /u+x -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a+x

RUN rm -fr /opt/java

FROM centos:7

ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'

        
RUN mkdir -p /opt

COPY --from=build /opt/songkong /opt/songkong
    
EXPOSE 4567

# Config, License, Logs, Reports and Internal Database
VOLUME /songkong

# Music folder should be mounted here
VOLUME /music

WORKDIR /opt/songkong

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/songkong/songkong.sh"]
CMD ["-r"]
```

Does anyone have any solution to allow me to use Alpine or similar sized alternative woith Java 11 on arm platform

Comment: Alpine docker image for ARMv6 and v7 is available and then you can add adoptJDK 11 JRE (arm32) to that. Would that work for you?

Comment: But i need an (openjdk) java build for arm32, I wouldnt know how to create that myself.

Comment: https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html is OpenJDK.